# Spring Tool Suite: NullpointerException at "Push In" operation

Tags: eclipse, aspectj, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I used Spring Tool Suite with Spring Roo to reverse engineer a database. Now I want to remove the AspectJ Files from my project and obtain standard JavaEE classes. 
To do so, I did a right click on my project --> Refactor --> Push In... 
After this, I get an error box saying that multiple problems have occurred (Java.lang.NullPointerException). Sometimes Spring Tool Suite then freezes and I have to close it with the task manager. In the error log I found the following error over and over again, as it seems to occur every 20 milliseconds. It also occurs when I only select a few classes and not the whole project. I would really appreciate, if somebody could help me solving this problem.

Here is the exception from the logfile:

```
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.refactoring.PushInRefactoringInputPage$3.update(PushInRefactoringInputPage.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2170)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.createItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTableViewer.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1458)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1696)
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.refactoring.PushInRefactoringInputPage.createTable(PushInRefactoringInputPage.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.refactoring.PushInRefactoringInputPage.createControl(PushInRefactoringInputPage.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2.createContents(RefactoringWizardDialog2.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.refactoring.PushInRefactoringAction.run(PushInRefactoringAction.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.ajdt.internal.ui.refactoring.PushInRefactoringAction.run(PushInRefactoringAction.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4410)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4228)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. It should be reported in eclipse bugzilla (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) against AJDT (which is where the 'Push In' refactoring that seems to be misbehaving here comes from).

Comment: For future reference, stackoverflow isn't really the right place for bug-reports. Its a question and answer site, and a bug-report isn't really a question.